# get types from array of class list

Tags: typescript

In Typescript we have way to access types from array as below.

```
const list = [item,item2] as const;
type typeOfArray = typeof list[number];

const something: typeOfArray = ; // item | item2
```

I have attempted to get that with class but getting "Property 'prototype' is missing in type error"

If I declare classes as type it works fine but can't access through `typeof`. Is this shortcoming of Typescript? If you have solution, will appreciate your help.

please use below code as sample
setup:

```
class A {
  methodA() {

  }
}

class B {
  methodB() {
    
  }
}

class C {
  methodC() {
    
  }
}

const classList = [A,B,C] as const;
```

This works just fine:

```
type classSelection = A | B | C;
let o: classSelection;

o = new A();
o. // o.methodA;
```

This is giving above error:

```
type classSelection = typeof classList[number];
o = new A();  //Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'typeof A | typeof B | typeof C'.
  Property 'prototype' is missing in type 'A' but required in type 'typeof C'
```

Comment: Your `ClassSelectionType` is a union of constructor types; if you want to turn that into a union of instance types you can use the `InstanceType` utility type like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WK7ByW); if that meets your needs I can write up an answer; let me know.

Comment: This is due to classes having both instance and static side at the same time. The semantics of `typeof` for them changes - with this operator, you get the static side, meaning you can only assign a constructor to `o` while what you are trying to assign is an instance, hence the error

Comment: @jcalz that is what I have been looking for. Thanks bunch! If you put as answer I will mark it. Might be helpful since there is no previous question related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `classList` variable is an array of class constructors:

```
const classList = [A, B, C] as const;
// const classList: readonly [typeof A, typeof B, typeof C]
```

Which means when you [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) its type with a `number` key type, you get a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of those constructor types:

```
type ClassConstructors = typeof classList[number];
// type ClassConstructors = typeof A | typeof B | typeof C
```

Class constructors are not themselves instances; instead, they have [construct signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) that look like `{new (): A}` (which means that using the [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) on it with no arguments will yield a value of type `A`).

There is [an `InstanceType<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype) which takes a type with a construct signature and returns the corresponding instance type.  If you apply it to a union of constructor types, you get a union of instance types:

```
type ClassSelection = InstanceType<typeof classList[number]>;
// type ClassSelection = A | B | C
```

And then the rest of your code should work:

```
let o: ClassSelection = new A(); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8CwAoa0C2BTALgCwHsATWACgEpFVV0BfVelVUSGAISrU10KLYs41ojRs3BRoAYU7ps+YpIHImXEdRTACAOwg5oLKABkAlrugBeaAG1YAGmht7kgLrRI+7boDcqAPS+PHT0DCBNdAC5oACcsMCJtEABPaxxEgAcsAgAzOHtUjOyHPPTMnJd1fKwpcQhJTxwogFdgHAIomEtKwpCwnCstRowAIywo5x8Uf2hK6tY6oKaWto7pksL4AB9VgpyOLa6yipLZqABlLBAsFuNtC2gASSCwLWAsABUSgB4D-Rre-sGIzGAD4JlMZpIaudLtdbpZNg5oFtJOpLnoCJFIaxoVccDctHctFgAO5wCheaBTAgAazAiSAA)